# LINQ Generic List cannot convert issue

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

```
public static List<Reservations> getReservations(int reservationId)
{
    return hoteldb.hotel_reservations.Where(x => x.reservation_id == reservationId).ToList();
}
```

I converted the values, I made sure that everything is good but to no avail.

It's not really working even the code below:

```
public List<Reservations> getReservations(int reservationId)
{
    return hoteldb.hotel_reservations.Where(x => x.reservation_room_desc == "sdfsfs").ToList();
}
```

Comment: What type is `hotel_reservations` and what type is `reservation_id` (I assume `int`)?

Comment: Do you have an error message ?

Comment: Can you post reservations class also is hoteldb static?

Comment: Shouldn't `Reservations` be called `Reservation`?

Comment: yes its int in database and in my model class

Comment: hoteldb is not static

Comment: The items in `hotel_reservations` are not of type `Reservations`, I am sure.

Comment: hahahaha , i was so depressed. thanks hristo

Comment: public List<hotel_reservations> getReservations(int reservationId)
        {
            var y = hoteldb.hotel_reservations.Where(x => x.reservation_room_desc == "sdfsfs").ToList();
            return y;
        }  //working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe getReservations() should use the type : `List<hotel_reservations>` ?

```
public List<hotel_reservations> getReservations(int reservationId) 
    {
        var y = hoteldb.hotel_reservations
               .Where(x => x.reservation_room_desc == "sdfsfs")
               .ToList(); 
        return y; 
    }
```